# spring mvc with jquery autocomplete returning list but not filtering

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

hi i am struggling spring mvc with autocomplete, it is going to method and returning list also but not filtering in auto complete text box please any body help me and fallowing is my code.

i tried with json and jquery also.

```
 in jsp
    ---------
    $(function() {$( "#clientName" ).autocomplete({
                source: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/getClientNames.htm'
                    });
    <label for="clientName">Search Client: </label>
                <input id="clientName" ></input>

    in spring method
    ----------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getClientNames",
                 method = RequestMethod.GET,
                 headers="Accept=application/json")
       public @ResponseBody List<String> getTechList(@RequestParam("term") String query,HttpServletResponse response) {
       // List<String> countryList = dummyDB.getTechList(query);
             //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
             List<String> clientList=new ArrayList<String>();
             clientList.add("Balu");
             clientList.add("Bala");
             clientList.add("Boss");
       return clientList;
       }

spring configuration file
-------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="app.com.db.controller" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> 
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: test RequestBody String query instead  RequestParam,If not affect please share all jquery ajax code

Comment: I have the same problem, would love to see an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "not filtering" but you don't use query param on your controller side. For example, it should looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getClientNames", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getTechList(@RequestParam("term") String query,HttpServletResponse response) {
   List<String> clientList=new ArrayList<String>();
   clientList.add("Balu");
   clientList.add("Bala");
   clientList.add("Boss");

   List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (String client : clientList) {
       if (client.contains(query)) {
         result.add(client);
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```